# Multiple frame movements in java

Tags: java, jframe

I have many frames. When I move from frame to frame making one invisible and the other visible the screen becomes blank. This means that the next frame opens after a delay. Is there any way to resolve this? 
Here is my code:

```
f.setVisible(false);
MyFrame1 f1=new MyFrame1();
f1.setVisible(true);
```

f is the object of my first frame,

f1 is the object of my second frame.

Comment: Wrooooong! [Obligatory answer!](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9554636/the-use-of-multiple-jframes-good-bad-practice)

Answer (score 0):

You can use a buffer for a smooth transition between frames. Also, setting f1 to visible without setting f to invisible, will also work. f will remain visible until f1 is painted over it.

Regarding design, I don't have much information about what you're trying to do, but there may be more efficient ways of painting objects.